# Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations, how to solve this error?

Tags: cleos, accounts, account-creation

I am creating an account to manage other accounts.

The command is

`$ cleos create account eosio accountadmin publickey1 publickey2`

But I am getting an error saying that provided keys, permissionsm and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations.

Both of these wallets are unlocked.

> Error Details:
>
> transaction declares authority
>   '{"actor":"eosio","permission":"active"}', but does not have
>   signatures for it.

This is the detail about the error.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the flag -p eosio@active to ensure that it's trying to utilize the correct auth? (I'm assuming that the wallet is unlocked and accessible and contains the correct keys)

Comment: this worked the first time around, but this time even with -p eosio@active it gives me the same error. Not sure why? Wallets are unlocked, accessible, contain the correct keys.

Comment: Still getting the error,  
`
cleos create account eosio accountadmin publickey1 publickey2 -p eosio@active
Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
Error Details:
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"eosio","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it.`

Comment: I had reset my blockchain and forgot to import eosio system account keys for default wallet again. 

That was causing the issue.
**RESOLVED**

Comment: could you expound on what you mean by "eosio system account keys"?